# MOSFET drain characteristics theoretical or practical?

Tags: mosfet

While reading the datasheet of the Si2302DS I've noticed these two points:

1. Rating of the continuous drain current as follows:

[image]

2. The drain characteristics:

[image]

The second picture suggests that at VGS=2 V, the drain saturates at around 1.1 V and the saturation current is about 7 A. How is that possible? It exceeds the absolute maximum current rating. If somebody tries to saturate it at VGS=2 V it will be destroyed. How does the manufacturer know this value? Even if the rating is 2.8 A, it will not possible to experimentally determine the value because the transistor will destroyed. Is this just a theoretical value?

Edit: the link for the datasheet is [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vishay.com/docs/70628/70628.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjhxZPktfL0AhWFj-YKHQ7WDjgQFnoECCwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2H9BL3qwut-APCpsTfTdD_)

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet in question. Note that the rating you quote is for maximum **continuous** current, not maximum instantaneous current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line following the screenshot posted is important:

[image]

And also the note *"a. Pulse width limited by maximum junction temperature."*

Comment: yes, got the point.